# reference form values in coldfusion using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, coldfusion

What I need to do is query a database if form values are 'like' any stored data, then return the results as a table (search form). The form action calls a javascript function. That function validates input and loads the table into the same div the form is in (ajax). In my coldfusion page is where I actually query, so I need to access those form field values there. My question is what/how is the best way to do this? #form.value# does not work because the form object isn't sent to coldfusion.

Do I:

Pass the DOM form object to the javascript function, and then pass that to coldfusion? If so, how?

Reference the form field values in my coldfusion page without the form actually submitting? If so, how? (The form does submit on a button click, but no refresh, only the javascript function call as explained above).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easiest to submit to an iframe and process the form there.

Answer (score 6):

Your javascript will be something like:

```
var theValue = $("#thefield").val();
$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "/processajax.cfm", data: {value: theValue}, dataType: "json", success: showResult });
```

Your ColdFusion code will include something like:

```
<cfcontent reset="true" type="application/json; charset=utf-8">
<cfset someData = doSearch(URL.value)>
<!--- Build data into array --->
<cfset dataArray = [...]>
<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(dataArray)#</cfoutput>
```

Then back in your javascript your callback function will execute where you then take the array data and build up the resulting html (or use a templating system to do that for you) and stick it in the desired div.